# Accessing items from array discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js, args

I am trying to make users able to select items from my array and have that gif / image printed within the channel it is sent in.
The bot will also check if whatever args the user sent is in the array, if it is the bot will proceed to send the image / gif. If it is not, the bot will sent the incorrect usage embed.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "anime",
  description: "Generates random anime gif",
  async execute(message, args) {
    let animearray = [
      "angry",
      "anime",
      "bite",
      "bored",
      "bread",
      "chocolate",
      "cookie",
      "cuddle",
      "dance",
      "drunk",
      "happy",
      "kill",
      "kiss",
      "laugh",
      "lick",
      "lonely",
      "pat",
      "poke",
      "pregnant",
      "punch",
      "run",
      "satouselfies",
      "sleep",
      "spank",
      "steal",
      "tickle",
    ];
    // incorrect usage 
    const inc = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`The category you selected is currently not avaiable. Please take a look at the current list by using: ${config.PREFIX}list`)
    .setColor('#E74C3C')

    //selecting a category from array 
    const announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ")
      if(!announcement) return message.reply(inc)

    // whatever was selected in const variable would be  the data
    const outc = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(data)
    .setColor('#E74C3C')
    
   



    await message.channel.send(outc);
  },
};
```

**Example**

User: <anime angry

Bot: Prints the angry image / gif (since it is in the array)

Comment: you're going to need a way to map the input, to the emoji name.  I would use an object, so you can index from the user input, and have the emoji name be the value of the key/value pair.  Then you don't have to loop the array to find the key=user_summited_value you would otherwise need to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope you're having a great day!

this was your code

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "anime",
  description: "Generates random anime gif",
  async execute(message, args) {
    let animearray = [
      "angry",
      "anime",
      "bite",
      "bored",
      "bread",
      "chocolate",
      "cookie",
      "cuddle",
      "dance",
      "drunk",
      "happy",
      "kill",
      "kiss",
      "laugh",
      "lick",
      "lonely",
      "pat",
      "poke",
      "pregnant",
      "punch",
      "run",
      "satouselfies",
      "sleep",
      "spank",
      "steal",
      "tickle",
    ];
    // incorrect usage 
    const inc = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`The category you selected is currently not avaiable. Please take a look at the current list by using: ${config.PREFIX}list`)
    .setColor('#E74C3C')

    //selecting a category from array 
    const announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ")
      if(!announcement) return message.reply(inc)

    // whatever was selected in const variable would be  the data
    const outc = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(data)
    .setColor('#E74C3C')
    
    await message.channel.send(outc);
  },
};
```

so all you need is to check if the `args.slice(1).join(" ")` exists in the array or no, so just do:

```js
if(!animearray.includes(args.slice(1).join(" ").toLowerCase())) return message.channel.send(inc)
```

else just check for the args and sent the image/gif depending on it.

*example:*

```js
if(args.slice(1).join(" ").toLowerCase() == 'dance') return message.channel.send(/* image/gif */)
```